# Is a light fixture with an ETL (Intertek) safety rating considered safe under NEC Guidelines?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I purchased 6 KnLnny Ware 4" recessed LED lights for my kitchen. In checking out the lights I noticed there isn't a UL certification only an ETL certification from Intertek. Is this an acceptable certification under the NEC?
[image]

Comment: Also important to check the actual listing to make sure it is legitimate and what standards were tested. Extreme made up example, but if it was certified and tested as a toaster then that doesn’t make it a safe light fixture. I have seen real examples of this with some more general testing of multi-use electrical device standards rather than the more applicable device-specific standards that more appropriately test the device per industry standard.

Comment: Here is the site to verify whether an Intertek/ETL product listing is legitimate and see what standards were tested for the certification: https://ramuk.intertekconnect.com/webclients/its/dlp/products.nsf/$$search?openform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Intertek is a Nationally Recognized Test Lab which tests to the nationally-accepted standards, many of which are drafted and/or maintained by UL (which also operates a test lab).

See [ETL Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.intertek.com/product-certification-marks/etl/guide/agreement/)

Answer (score 2):

ETL is indeed a qualified NRTL…

… but buying a fixture from what is obviously a "throwaway" brand is probably short-sighted.   Most of that stuff is designed to only survive the 30-day Amazon return window, and shaved for cost in every conceivable way.

Also note that many times, the ETL is only claimed in the product listing, it's not actually on the product.  Doesn't count.

Comment: “it's not actually on the product” It’s hard to be positive with such a highly-compressed image, but it looks to me like the sticker on the wire says “ETL” and “Intertek” and I’m pretty sure the same is embossed into the driver cover too. Whether the marks are genuine on a trash brand like this is a whole other question, but they do appear to be present.

Comment: Easy enough to look up a product listing with ETL/Intertek for yourself if you believe the listing is dubious: https://ramuk.intertekconnect.com/webclients/its/dlp/products.nsf/$$search?openform